# How to know if urllib.urlretrieve succeeds?

Tags: python, networking, urllib

`urllib.urlretrieve` returns silently even if the file doesn't exist on the remote http server, it just saves a html page to the named file. For example:

```
urllib.urlretrieve('http://google.com/abc.jpg', 'abc.jpg')
```

just returns silently, even if abc.jpg doesn't exist on google.com server, the generated `abc.jpg` is not a valid jpg file, it's actually a html page . I guess the returned headers (a httplib.HTTPMessage instance) can be used to actually tell whether the retrieval successes or not, but I can't find any doc for `httplib.HTTPMessage`.

Can anybody provide some information about this problem?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Consider using `urllib2` if it possible in your case.  It is more advanced and easy to use than `urllib`.

You can detect any HTTP errors easily:

```
>>> import urllib2
>>> resp = urllib2.urlopen("http://google.com/abc.jpg")
Traceback (most recent call last):
<<MANY LINES SKIPPED>>
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

`resp` is actually `HTTPResponse` object that you can do a lot of useful things with:

```
>>> resp = urllib2.urlopen("http://google.com/")
>>> resp.code
200
>>> resp.headers["content-type"]
'text/html; charset=windows-1251'
>>> resp.read()
"<<ACTUAL HTML>>"
```

Comment: Can urllib2 provide the caching behavior of urlretrieve though? Or would we have to reimplement it?

Comment: See this awersome recipie from ActiveState: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/491261/

We're using it in our current project, works flawlessly

Comment: urlopen does not provide a hook function (to show progress bar for example) like urlretrieve.

Comment: You can hook your own function:

fp = open(local, 'wb')
totalSize = int(h["Content-Length"])
blockSize = 8192 # same value as in urllib.urlretrieve
count = 0
while True:
 chunk = resp.read(blockSize)
 if not chunk: break
 fp.write(chunk)
 count += 1
 dlProgress(count, blockSize, totalSize) # The hook!

fp.flush()
fp.close()

Answer (score 7):

I keep it simple:

```
# Simple downloading with progress indicator, by Cees Timmerman, 16mar12.

import urllib2

remote = r"http://some.big.file"
local = r"c:\downloads\bigfile.dat"

u = urllib2.urlopen(remote)
h = u.info()
totalSize = int(h["Content-Length"])

print "Downloading %s bytes..." % totalSize,
fp = open(local, 'wb')

blockSize = 8192 #100000 # urllib.urlretrieve uses 8192
count = 0
while True:
    chunk = u.read(blockSize)
    if not chunk: break
    fp.write(chunk)
    count += 1
    if totalSize > 0:
        percent = int(count * blockSize * 100 / totalSize)
        if percent > 100: percent = 100
        print "%2d%%" % percent,
        if percent < 100:
            print "\b\b\b\b\b",  # Erase "NN% "
        else:
            print "Done."

fp.flush()
fp.close()
if not totalSize:
    print
```

Comment: A better idea is `shutil.copyfileobj`.

Comment: @CeesTimmerman Amazing solution! Solve a big problem of memory consumption for me! Cheers!

Answer (score 5):

According to the documentation is is [undocumented](http://bugs.python.org/issue3428)

to get access to the message it looks like you do something like:

```
a, b=urllib.urlretrieve('http://google.com/abc.jpg', r'c:\abc.jpg')
```

b is the message instance

Since I have learned that Python it is always useful to use Python's ability to be introspective when I type

```
dir(b)
```

I see lots of methods or functions to play with

And then I started doing things with b

for example

```
b.items()
```

Lists lots of interesting things, I suspect that playing around with these things will allow you to get the attribute you want to manipulate.

Sorry this is such a beginner's answer but I am trying to master how to use the introspection abilities to improve my learning and your questions just popped up.

Well I tried something interesting related to this-I was wondering if I could automatically get the output from each of the things that showed up in the directory that did not need parameters so I wrote:

```
needparam=[]
for each in dir(b):
    x='b.'+each+'()'
    try:
        eval(x)
        print x
    except:
        needparam.append(x)
```

Comment: No status for me, and your code only works once. Try `for k in b: print "%s: %r" % (k, b[k])`

Answer (score 2):

You can create a new URLopener (inherit from FancyURLopener) and throw exceptions or handle errors any way you want. Unfortunately, FancyURLopener ignores 404 and other errors. See this question:

[How to catch 404 error in urllib.urlretrieve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1308542/how-to-catch-404-error-in-urllib-urlretrieve)

Answer (score 1):

I ended up with my own `retrieve` implementation, with the help of `pycurl` it supports more protocols than urllib/urllib2, hope it can help other people.

```
import tempfile
import pycurl
import os

def get_filename_parts_from_url(url):
    fullname = url.split('/')[-1].split('#')[0].split('?')[0]
    t = list(os.path.splitext(fullname))
    if t[1]:
        t[1] = t[1][1:]
    return t

def retrieve(url, filename=None):
    if not filename:
        garbage, suffix = get_filename_parts_from_url(url)
        f = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix = '.' + suffix, delete=False)
        filename = f.name
    else:
        f = open(filename, 'wb')
    c = pycurl.Curl()
    c.setopt(pycurl.URL, str(url))
    c.setopt(pycurl.WRITEFUNCTION, f.write)
    try:
        c.perform()
    except:
        filename = None
    finally:
        c.close()
        f.close()
    return filename
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyURLopener(urllib.FancyURLopener):
    http_error_default = urllib.URLopener.http_error_default

url = "http://page404.com"
filename = "download.txt"
def reporthook(blockcount, blocksize, totalsize):
    pass
    ...

try:
    (f,headers)=MyURLopener().retrieve(url, filename, reporthook)
except Exception, e:
    print e
```

Answer (score 0):

:) My first post on StackOverflow, have been a lurker for years. :)

Sadly dir(urllib.urlretrieve) is deficient in useful information.
So from this thread thus far I tried writing this:

```
a,b = urllib.urlretrieve(imgURL, saveTo)
print "A:", a
print "B:", b
```

which produced this:

```
A: /home/myuser/targetfile.gif
B: Accept-Ranges: bytes
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Cache-Control: max-age=604800
Content-Type: image/gif
Date: Mon, 07 Mar 2016 23:37:34 GMT
Etag: "4e1a5d9cc0857184df682518b9b0da33"
Last-Modified: Sun, 06 Mar 2016 21:16:48 GMT
Server: ECS (hnd/057A)
Timing-Allow-Origin: *
X-Cache: HIT
Content-Length: 27027
Connection: close
```

I guess one can check:

```
if b.Content-Length > 0:
```

My next step is to test a scenario where the retrieve fails...

Comment: b.getheader('Content-length') would normally be greater than 0 even on 404 (if the file does not exist)

Answer (score 0):

Results against another server/website - what comes back in "B" is a bit random, but one can test for certain values:

```
A: get_good.jpg
B: Date: Tue, 08 Mar 2016 00:44:19 GMT
Server: Apache
Last-Modified: Sat, 02 Jan 2016 09:17:21 GMT
ETag: "524cf9-18afe-528565aef9ef0"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 101118
Connection: close
Content-Type: image/jpeg

A: get_bad.jpg
B: Date: Tue, 08 Mar 2016 00:44:20 GMT
Server: Apache
Content-Length: 1363
X-Frame-Options: deny
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html
```

In the 'bad' case (non-existing image file) "B" retrieved a small chunk of (Googlebot?) HTML code and saved it as the target, hence Content-Length of 1363 bytes.