# How to catch 404 error in urllib.urlretrieve

Tags: python, http, url, urllib

Background: I am using [`urllib.urlretrieve`](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.6/python/library/urllib.html), as opposed to any other function in the `urllib*` modules, because of the hook function support (see `reporthook` below) .. which is used to display a textual progress bar. This is Python >=2.6.

```
>>> urllib.urlretrieve(url[, filename[, reporthook[, data]]])
```

However, `urlretrieve` is so dumb that it leaves no way to detect the status of the HTTP request (eg: was it 404 or 200?).

```
>>> fn, h = urllib.urlretrieve('http://google.com/foo/bar')
>>> h.items() 
[('date', 'Thu, 20 Aug 2009 20:07:40 GMT'),
 ('expires', '-1'),
 ('content-type', 'text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1'),
 ('server', 'gws'),
 ('cache-control', 'private, max-age=0')]
>>> h.status
''
>>>
```

What is the best known way to download a remote HTTP file with hook-like support (to show progress bar) and a decent HTTP error handling?

Comment: Not providing an HTTP Status on your request should probably be considered a bug in the stdlib (but check out the far better library, requests, below)

Comment: it's so stupid that urlretrieve can't handle this with a return status

Answer (score 28):

Check out `urllib.urlretrieve`'s complete code:

```
def urlretrieve(url, filename=None, reporthook=None, data=None):
  global _urlopener
  if not _urlopener:
    _urlopener = FancyURLopener()
  return _urlopener.retrieve(url, filename, reporthook, data)
```

In other words, you can use [urllib.FancyURLopener](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#urllib.FancyURLopener) (it's part of the public urllib API). You can override `http_error_default` to detect 404s:

```
class MyURLopener(urllib.FancyURLopener):
  def http_error_default(self, url, fp, errcode, errmsg, headers):
    # handle errors the way you'd like to

fn, h = MyURLopener().retrieve(url, reporthook=my_report_hook)
```

Comment: I don't want to specify handlers; does it throw exceptions like urllib2.urlopen?

Comment: It's very easy to make it throw. FancyURLopener subclasses URLopener which does throw, so you can try calling the base class's implementation: def http_error_default(...): URLopener.http_error_default(...)

Comment: You should rather do opener = MyURLopener() and then opener.retrieve() to keep the opener object alive. Otherwise (if you do all on a single line) the newly created opener will be immediately deallocated right after the retrieve operation. This will erase the temporary file the data was downloaded to before you have a chance to use it.

Answer (score 15):

You should use:

```
import urllib2

try:
    resp = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.google.com/this-gives-a-404/")
except urllib2.URLError, e:
    if not hasattr(e, "code"):
        raise
    resp = e

print "Gave", resp.code, resp.msg
print "=" * 80
print resp.read(80)
```

*Edit:* The rationale here is that unless you expect the exceptional state, it is an exception for it to happen, and you probably didn't even think about it -- so instead of letting your code continue to run while it was unsuccessful, the default behavior is--quite sensibly--to inhibit its execution.

Answer (score 2):

The URL Opener object's "retreive" method supports the reporthook and throws an exception on 404.

http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#url-opener-objects

Answer (score 1):

Here is an updated answer for Python 3 (below solution tested in Python 3.10) :

> urlretrieve is so dumb that it leaves no way to detect the status of the HTTP request (eg: was it 404 or 200?).

- If the call to urlretrieve does not trigger any exception, it was probably a 200 OK or another 20X code. It is possible there was redirect before; and the behaviour is still the same in Python 3.10.
- For errors, you can catch them as HTTPError objects, which include the error code. So you can determine if it was a 404 or another error code.
- You can add another generic exception clause for others cases : writing permissions, invalid destination filename...

```py
from urllib.error import HTTPError
from urllib.request import urlretrieve

try:
    local_file, headers = urlretrieve("https://google.com/thats/a/404/url", "./output.txt")
except HTTPError as e:
    print("Error, HTTP Code is {}".format(e.code))
    if e.code == 404:
        print("This is a 404 NOT FOUND")
except Exception as e:
    print("Another exception which is not an HTTP error was raised. (Invalid destination filename, innapropriate permissions... etc)")
```

> What is the best known way to download a remote HTTP file with hook-like support (to show progress bar) and a decent HTTP error handling?

If you want a progress bar, and better error handling, it is simpler to drop urlretrieve, and use `requests` with `tqdm` instead:

```
pip install tqdm
pip install requests
```

```py
import requests
from tqdm import tqdm

def download(url: str, fname: str, chunk_size=1024):
    resp = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    total = int(resp.headers.get('content-length', 0))
    with open(fname, 'wb') as file, tqdm(
            desc=fname,
            total=total,
            unit='iB',
            unit_scale=True,
            unit_divisor=1024,
    ) as bar:
        for data in resp.iter_content(chunk_size=chunk_size):
            size = file.write(data)
            bar.update(size)
    return resp.status_code

code = download("https://google.com/not_a_valid_file.txt", "output2.txt")

if code == 404:
    print("The file was not found")
```

This code is a modified version of : https://gist.github.com/yanqd0/c13ed29e29432e3cf3e7c38467f42f51 from github user *yanqd0*