# How do I catch a specific HTTP error in Python?

Tags: python, http, urllib2, urllib

I have

```
import urllib2
try:
   urllib2.urlopen("some url")
except urllib2.HTTPError:
   <whatever>
```

but what I end up is catching any kind of HTTP error. I want to catch only if the specified webpage doesn't exist (404?).

Comment: Have tried the recipe in this post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1308542/how-to-catch-404-error-in-urllib-urlretrieve

Answer (score 165, accepted):

**Python 3**

```
from urllib.error import HTTPError
```

**Python 2**

```
from urllib2 import HTTPError
```

Just catch `HTTPError`, handle it, and if it's not Error 404, simply use `raise` to re-raise the exception.

See the [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions).

Here is a complete example for Python 2:

```
import urllib2
from urllib2 import HTTPError
try:
   urllib2.urlopen("some url")
except HTTPError as err:
   if err.code == 404:
       <whatever>
   else:
       raise
```

Comment: can i do urllib2.urlopen("*") to handle any 404 errors and route them to my 404.html page?

Comment: @TobiasKolb: Since the question is tagged `urllib2` (after all, it's over 9 years old) and `urllib3` is not part of the standard library, I think that wouldn't fit here. If there isn't a duplicate already, maybe open a new question? Or use `urllib` as outlined in Lazik's answer below.

Comment: I'm writing regression tests, so I want access to the urlopen response even if it was a 404.  Even if I assign the value from the `urllib2.urlopen("some url")` , I can't use that value inside the exception -- it will cause another exception.  So, how do I get the response text of the 404 page that was  returned?

Comment: I found the answer: You can use the HTTPError instance as a response.    https://docs.python.org/3/howto/urllib2.html#httperror

Answer (score 50):

For Python 3.x

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.error
try:
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, fullpath)
except urllib.error.HTTPError as err:
    print(err.code)
```

Comment: urllib.request.urlretrieve() is legacy python 2 interface   . . . 
 https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#legacy-interface

Comment: Shouldn't the except line be "except HTTPError as err:" since you imported a specific thing?.  Or am I just such a beginner that I'm even wrong on that?

Comment: @JeopardyTempest I have fixed the import

Answer (score 5):

Tim's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3193387/10323798) seems to me as misleading especially when `urllib2` does not return the expected code. For example, this error will be fatal (believe or not - it is not uncommon one when downloading urls):

> AttributeError: 'URLError' object has no attribute 'code'

Fast, but maybe not the best solution would be code using nested try/except block:

```
import urllib2
try:
    urllib2.urlopen("some url")
except urllib2.HTTPError as err:
    try:
        if err.code == 404:
            # Handle the error
        else:
            raise
    except:
        ...
```

More information to the topic of nested try/except blocks [Are nested try/except blocks in python a good programming practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17015230/are-nested-try-except-blocks-in-python-a-good-programming-practice)

Answer (score 2):

If `from urllib.error import HTTPError` doesn't work, try using `from requests.exceptions import HTTPError`.

Sample:

```
from requests.exceptions import HTTPError

try:
    <access some url>
except HTTPError:
    # Handle the error like ususal
```