# Python Selenium - Try/Except does not work

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a Selenium script, where I enter a series of websites, and get some data. Sometimes the data does not exist, and I simply want to write something like "Cant find x data" onto my string. The current script does this:

```
#Getting "Status"
try:
    strValue = strValue + ',' + browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#visKTTabset > div.h-tab-content > div.h-tab-content-inner > div:nth-child(12) > table > tbody > tr.stripes-even > td:nth-child(3) > span').text
except webdriver.NoSuchElementException:
    StrValue = strValue + ',' + "Status not found"
```

The script works when the "Status" actually exists, but id does not get into the "except" part. The top of my script has this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Selenium\chromedriver.exe')
browser.get('https://motorregister.skat.dk/dmr-front/dmr.portal?_nfpb=true&_nfpb=true&_pageLabel=vis_koeretoej_side&_nfls=false')
browser.implicitly_wait(10)  # Will set the global wait to 10 seconds.gnash
```

I tried the solution here: [Try except in python/selenium still throwing NoSuchElementException error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48179010/try-except-in-python-selenium-still-throwing-nosuchelementexception-error) but it didnt work.

Comment: Do you define `strValue` before the `try/except` ?

Comment: It returns an exit code so it doesn’t qualify for the exception

Comment: @anonjnr I get this error: 
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"#visKTTabset > div.h-tab-content > div.h-tab-content-inner > div:nth-child(12) > table > tbody > tr.stripes-even > td:nth-child(4) > span"}

Comment: @andreihondrari I do :)

Comment: See answer below. Also you could do something like strValue = 0 and use an if Statement instead of the try block?

Answer (score 1):

Python names are case sensitive, so perhaps you need:

```
strValue = strValue + ',' + "Status not found"
```

Comment: Good point! That fixed some other issues that I had! Thank you

Comment: Just one other note: the Pythonic way of naming variables is dash_case not camelCase. So str_value is more appropriate. :)

Answer (score 0):

`NoSuchElementException` is not part of `webdriver`, it's part of `selenium.common.exceptions`

```
try:
    strValue = strValue + ',' + browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#visKTTabset > div.h-tab-content > div.h-tab-content-inner > div:nth-child(12) > table > tbody > tr.stripes-even > td:nth-child(3) > span').text
except NoSuchElementException:  # without webdriver.
    StrValue = strValue + ',' + "Status not found"
```

And make sure `strValue` is declared before the `try except` block.

As a side note, in Python `strValue` should be `str_value`

Comment: Thank you so much. I've been stuck with this, for far too long, your solution - along with Brunns answer helped out