# How can I use a non-zero returncode to send email to a backup address using smtplib?

Tags: python, python-3.x, smtplib, return-code

I am experimenting with `smtplib` in Python3.
I want to send the content of a variable to an email address. If there is an `smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError`, I want to send that variable to an alternative email address. This works (see code below). But what if I want to add a third email address (if the first two fail for some reason)?
I don't think `try` and `except` allow me to add another block of the same code (with different email login details).
I know with `subprocess`, it's possible to acquire the `returncode` of a variable and then use `if`.
For example:

```
result = subprocess.run(["ls", "-al"], capture_output = True)
if result !=0:
    do_something_to_list_the_directory
```

I don't know how this can be done without using `subprocess`. Can anyone please advise?
Code below:

```
try:
    mail_sending_attempt = smtplib.SMTP("smtp_provider", 587)
    mail_sending_attempt.starttls()
    mail_sending_attempt.login(send, passinfo)    ### this will not work
    mail_sending_attempt.sendmail(send, receive, message)
    mail_sending_attempt.quit() 
    
except Exception:
    mail_sending_attempt = smtplib.SMTP("smtp_provider", 587)
    mail_sending_attempt.starttls()
    mail_sending_attempt.login(send2, passinfo2)    ### this will not work
    mail_sending_attempt.sendmail(send2, receive2, message)
    mail_sending_attempt.quit()
```

Comment: Why not use a nested `try`-`except` within the first `except` block? See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17015230/are-nested-try-except-blocks-in-python-a-good-programming-practice

Answer (score 0):

In case there are more email, you can use following snippet

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class EmailData:
    send: str
    passinfo: str
    receive: str


main = EmailData("send1", "passinfo1", "receive1")
backup_1 = EmailData("send2", "passinfo2", "receive2")
...

for data in [main, backup_1, ...]:
    try:
        mail_sending_attempt = smtplib.SMTP("smtp_provider", 587)
        mail_sending_attempt.starttls()
        mail_sending_attempt.login(data.send, data.passinfo)
        mail_sending_attempt.sendmail(data.send, data.receive, message)
        mail_sending_attempt.quit()
        break
    except Exception:
        continue
else:
    # the case when we won't encounter break, so every login failed.
    raise Exception
```