# How to catch http error 404 with urllib3?

Tags: python, http, urllib3

### What I'm trying to do

I'm requesting a file from an API. If the file does't exist, I get a 404.

### What I tried

I'm trying to handle this, using [`urllib3`](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

I found a lot of great, but outdated (~10 years old), documentation how to do this with with [`urllib` and `urllib2`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3193060/catch-specific-http-error-in-python/30327459).

How does this work in [`urllib3`](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html)?

All I found in their docs was this

```py
try:
    http.request('GET', 'nx.example.com', retries=False)
except urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError:
    print('Connection failed.')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply look at the status code:

```py
import urllib3

http = urllib3.PoolManager()
r = http.request("GET", "httpbin.org/status/404")
if r.status == 404:
    print("404!")
```