# Try except for HTTP Error when accessing link

Tags: python, http, error-handling

I am looping through links and there are times when link can not be reached. I get back an HTTPERROR listed below

This is the code I am trying to run so if I get HTTPError Sleep for 5 minutes and try again.

```
    try:
        content, _ = http_request_get(url=polylink,payload={'t':''},parse=True)
    except HTTPError:
        print('Link Fail wait 5 Minutes try Again')
        time.sleep(300)
        continue
```

This is the error I get

```
HTTPError   Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\Users\UserName\Documents\DataScience\Stocks\PolygonStockData2.py in 
     110             print(polylink)
     111             try:
---> 112                 content, _ = http_request_get(url=polylink,payload={'t':''},parse=True)
     113             except HTTPError:
     114                 print('Link Fail wait 5 Minutes try Again')
```

Why wont my try catch ever get to the sleep command to try again?

Comment: Are you catching the same `HTTPError` class that is being thrown…?

Comment: How is `HTTPError` defined?  Are you importing it from somewhere?

Comment: I am importing in HTTPEror from here

Comment: from urllib.error import HTTPError

Comment: deceze.. Probably not I was getting an error becuase HTTPError was not defined so I just but in the import just like it was recommended in this post.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3193060/catch-specific-http-error-in-python