# try/catch not catching HTTPError

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, try-catch

I have some basic code that tries to request a page using BeautifulSoup:

```
from bs4 import *
from urllib.request import urlopen

try:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen('http://badsite.com/404'))
except urllib.exceptions.HTTPError:
    pass
```

This still raises:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
HTTPError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-a0aa8eb7a9ee> in <module>
```

I have substituted `urllib.exceptions.HTTPError` for `requests.HTTPError` and `requests.exceptions.HTTPError`. All of them still fail to catch the error. How do I properly catch an HTTPError?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `urllib.error.HTTPError`? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19172223/14170431) answer might help.