# How do I skip if the response is 404 using python requests?

Tags: python, python-requests, http-status-code-404

```
for user in comments['comment_id']:
  try:
    get_profile(user)
  except urllib.error.HTTPError:
    continue
```

and I have gotten error like this, I don't know how to solve this problem

```
<ipython-input-38-c9a67ae2e3f1> in <module>()
      2 for user in comments['comment_id']:
      3   try:
----> 4     get_profile(user)
      5   except urllib.error.HTTPError:
      6     continue

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/requests/models.py in raise_for_status(self)
    939 
    940         if http_error_msg:
--> 941             raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
    942 
    943     def close(self):

HTTPError: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://m.facebook.com/344608967148594/about/
```

Comment: What is `get_profile`? Is it using the `requests` module? Because it looks like you are just catching the wrong HTTPError class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for user in comments['comment_id']:
  try:
    get_profile(user)
  except:
    continue
```

Comment: While this works, it catches _all_ exceptions, not just the 404 response. It's best practice to catch a _specific_ exception.

Comment: maybe you can try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3193060/how-do-i-catch-a-specific-http-error-in-python I hope it helps