# python urllib2 library simple http_error_default error handler

Tags: python, urllib2

This is how my class looks like:

```
class ExtHTTPErrorProcessor (urllib2.BaseHandler):

def http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs):
    print code
    return res
...
...
opener = urllib2.build_opener(ExtHTTPErrorProcessor())
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
urllib2.urlopen(request, data)
```

All it does is to handle all error code. I follow exactly format from the documentation: http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.BaseHandler.http_error_default
When error code 400 comes in, it does not call my http_error_default at all, it is calling the one inside urllib2.
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 521, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
    urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request

I tried adding the method http_error_400, then this method will be called, but I really need the http_error_default. I really need a default one.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this vague old thread](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-bugs-list/2006-February/032155.html) you must specify explicit handlers in the "Fancy" URL Opener... I'm sticking with [my simple working solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9740603/819417). Just add a try ... except block.