# Downloading images using Python that no longer exist

Tags: python, urllib

I have a script that downloads images from Google. However, as you might have experienced yourself, Google sometimes still shows images in its results that are no longer online, resulting in an error page. How can I tell Python not to bother downloading it if it's no longer there?

Right now I simply use `urllib.urlretrieve()`, the content of which gets written to `image.jpg`. How can I let Python know that it doesn't need to try to download the image if it  no longer exists?

Comment: [Duplicate?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/987876/645270)

Comment: What happen when the image don't exist anymore? html error code in the result object probably.