# Python and Urllib. How to handle the network exceptions?

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, ubuntu, urllib

I'm working on a simple code that is `downloading a file over HTTP` using the package `urllib` and `urllib.request`. Everything is working good excepted that I would like to be able to handle the network problems that could happens.

- Checking if the computer is online (Connected to the internet). And proceed only if true.
- Restarting the download of the file if during it, the connection is lost or too bad.

I would like, if possible, to use as less packages as possible. 
Here is my actual code :

```
import urllib
import urllib.request
url = "http://my.site.com/myFile"
urlSplited = url.split('/')[-1];
print ("Downloading : "+urlSplited)
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, urlSplited)
```

To check if a connection is etablished, I believe I can do something like

```
while connection() is true:
   Download()
```

But that would do the downloading many times..

I'm working on Linux.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use a combination of try, while and sleep function. Like this:

```
import urllib
import urllib.request
import time
url = "http://my.site.com/myFile"
urlSplited = url.split('/')[-1];
try_again = True
print ("Downloading : "+urlSplited)

while try_again:
    try:
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, urlSplited, timeout = 100)
        try_again = False
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        time.sleep(600)
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace **while** with **if**, then everything under it will run only once.

```
if connection() == True:
   Download()
```

Also, connection() function could be something like this:

```
try:    
    urllib.urlopen(url, timeout=5)
    return True
return False
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Will the `try` also work while the `urlopen` function is working ? I mean, if during the download the connection is lost ?

Comment: You specified that connection() should check whether the connection was established, so this function runs only once at the start, returns a value, and stops. If you're worried about the file downloading correctly, you should check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/987876/how-to-know-if-urllib-urlretrieve-succeeds) (and probably use urllib2)