# HTTPS Link using urllib.urlretrieve in Python

Tags: python, urllib, urlretrieve

I'm using this code and it works fine when using HTTP but it is not working when connecting over HTTPS

```
import urllib
import ssl
(fn,hd) = urllib.urlretrieve('http://host.com/file.py')
execfile(fn)
```

Does anyone know how to connect to HTTPS using the same code?

Thanks for the help all.

Answer (score 0):

try replacing http with https.

answers on this topic pretty much cover it:  [How to know if urllib.urlretrieve succeeds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/987876/how-to-know-if-urllib-urlretrieve-succeeds)